# Heroku ajax calls return error

Tags: php, ajax, heroku

I have a php app which worked perfectly on a dedicated server. Once i migrated to heroku the ajax calls started returning errors, such as couldn't load.

For example the following code return error. The album_handle.php file exists on the server.

```
var url = "album_handle.php?id=" + album_images.id;
$('#ajaxholder').load(url, "",
        function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            $("#dvloader").hide();
            if(textStatus == 'error') {
                $('#ajaxholder').html('<p>There was an error making the AJAX request</p>');
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: But what error are you actually getting on the server that is causing the AJAX call to fail?

Comment: sorry, my bad. return 500 error

Comment: Well it sounds like you have some bad server configuration in Heroku. Have you run all appropriate DB migrations?

Comment: hi the project doesn't use a database.

Comment: Have you check your server logs for any signs of what the error may be.?

Comment: Hi, I use GD functions. They have returned error. I guess GD is not installed in Heroku. Any clues how i can get that done ?

Comment: I am not sure. You might best use Heroku support to resolve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with ajax calls in heroku. The ajax calls in here process php gd functions. Since certain php gd functions doesn't work on heroku the issue is raised.